# Calculate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(a\cosh(x)) \, dx$

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, quantum-field-theory

I got into trouble when I tried to calculate this integral while doing a quantum field theory ( QFT ) problem:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\sin\left(\,{a\cosh\left(\,{x}\,\right)}\right)\,{\rm d}x
$$
The value is $\pi\operatorname{J}_{0}\left(\,{a}\,\right)$, where $\operatorname{J}_{n}\left(\,{x}\,\right)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind.

How can I prove it analytically?

Comment: There is a problem somewhere : either there is a typo in the integrand or the answer is wrong

Comment: Agreed with @ClaudeLeibovici Checked also via W. Mathematica. For example, if $a = 1$, the numerical integration gives $1.821(...)$ where as $\pi J_0(1) = 2.4039(...)$

Comment: @Laplacian and @Claude Leibovici the answer is:$\pi  J_0(a)$ is correct, try: `NIntegrate[Sin[Cosh[x]], {x, -1000, 1000}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
 MaxRecursion -> 20]` for: $a=1$

Comment: Using only Mathematica: `InverseLaplaceTransform[
 Integrate[
  LaplaceTransform[Sin[a Cosh[x]], a, s], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> s > 0], s, a]` we have:`\[Pi] BesselJ[0, a]`.

Comment: Yes, I found the same problem in Mathematica. Seems that Mathematica could run into unexpected problems while dealing with such oscillating but integrable functions. How can I prove this expression analytically?

Comment: Got it. Using Laplace transform according to a and the inverse. Thanks @MariuszIwaniuk

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Oh, that was unexpected! Thank you!!

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk. Thanks for your comment